# Replace table value in fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart

I have a database name `q8marketz` there is a table `product` inside. This table has many fields eg:- product id, model, quantity, shipping, etc...

I have uploaded many products to my table... there is a field `shipping`, the `shipping` value is already set to `1`for all products, so now I want to set all product shipping values to `0`.

anybody can help me? 
Sorry my English is not perfect...

Two product details given below...

```
===Database q8marketz

== Table structure for table product

|------
|Field|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**product_id**//|int(11)|No|
|model|varchar(64)|No|
|downpayment|varchar(32)|No|
|sku|varchar(64)|No|
|upc|varchar(12)|No|
|ean|varchar(14)|No|
|jan|varchar(13)|No|
|isbn|varchar(13)|No|
|mpn|varchar(64)|No|
|location|varchar(128)|No|
|quantity|int(4)|No|0
|stock_status_id|int(11)|No|
|image|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|manufacturer_id|int(11)|No|
|shipping|tinyint(1)|No|1
|price|decimal(15,4)|No|0.0000
|points|int(8)|No|0
|tax_class_id|int(11)|No|
|date_available|date|No|
|weight|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|weight_class_id|int(11)|No|0
|length|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|width|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|height|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|length_class_id|int(11)|No|0
|subtract|tinyint(1)|No|1
|minimum|int(11)|No|1
|sort_order|int(11)|No|0
|status|tinyint(1)|No|0
|date_added|datetime|No|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|date_modified|datetime|No|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|viewed|int(5)|No|0
== Dumping data for table product

|886|BA-HANDBAGS-001ss| | | | | | | |aaaa|95|7|data/hand-bags.jpg|7|1|32.5000|25|0|2012-09-03|0.00000000|1|0.00000000|0.00000000|0.00000000|1|1|1|1|1|2012-09-25 13:00:18|0000-00-00 00:00:00|0
|883|BA-HANDBAGS-001ss| | | | | | | |aaaa|95|7|data/hand-bags.jpg|7|1|32.5000|25|0|2012-09-03|0.00000000|1|0.00000000|0.00000000|0.00000000|1|1|1|1|1|2012-09-17 14:08:08|2012-09-25 13:00:06|9
== Table structure for table product

|------
|Field|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**product_id**//|int(11)|No|
|model|varchar(64)|No|
|downpayment|varchar(32)|No|
|sku|varchar(64)|No|
|upc|varchar(12)|No|
|ean|varchar(14)|No|
|jan|varchar(13)|No|
|isbn|varchar(13)|No|
|mpn|varchar(64)|No|
|location|varchar(128)|No|
|quantity|int(4)|No|0
|stock_status_id|int(11)|No|
|image|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|manufacturer_id|int(11)|No|
|shipping|tinyint(1)|No|1
|price|decimal(15,4)|No|0.0000
|points|int(8)|No|0
|tax_class_id|int(11)|No|
|date_available|date|No|
|weight|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|weight_class_id|int(11)|No|0
|length|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|width|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|height|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|length_class_id|int(11)|No|0
|subtract|tinyint(1)|No|1
|minimum|int(11)|No|1
|sort_order|int(11)|No|0
|status|tinyint(1)|No|0
|date_added|datetime|No|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|date_modified|datetime|No|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|viewed|int(5)|No|0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use an update query like this:

```
update product set shipping=0;
```

This will update *all* the rows to 0.

If you want to only specify certain selected rows, you can add a `where` clause to limit the number of rows that you update like this:

```
update product set shipping=0 where points>2;
```

This would update all the rows where `points` has a value greater than 2.

Edit: The code can be run directly from the mysql console, or via a database call from within PHP like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO($hostname, $username, $password);
$sql='update product set shipping=0 where points>2';
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
```

Comment: @Mansoorabbas You might also be interested in reading this rather long question and answer I [wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) which could well help you with SQL once you get your feet wet with single table bits :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL UPDATE statement to update existing records in your table.

SQL UPDATE Syntax :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

For your examlpe use :

```
UPDATE product
SET shipping=0;
```

==>The code can be run directly from the mysql console.

To use PHP Call try the code:

```
<?php
 $dataBase = new PDO($hostname, $username, $password);
 $sqlQuery ='update product set shipping=0';
 $stmt = $dataBase->query($sqlQuery );
?>
```